# Codeigniter in subdomain gives the index of page instead of the index.php

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, subdomain

I have a site I developed with CI 2.1.3

Here is my folders structure at **localhost**:

```
/mysite
       /application
       /system
       /public_html
                   /index.php
                   /assets
```

In the `public_html` folder I have the following `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /test/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
Options -Indexes
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
```

I created a subdomain on the live server called `dev`.
The directory for it is `public_html/dev`

I uploaded the site to this directory.

Trying to go to the site I get the index of/ page and I see the directories inside dev but not the site.

Any idea how to fix that?

I tried changing the base_url in the config file, which was empty and it didn't help.
I tried all kinds of combinations in the htaccess file, nothing works.

Can some please help?
I tried without the RewriteBase as well.
I also tried:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

and
`DirectoryIndex public_html/index.php`

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the rewriterule to

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Ok, the dev folder was actually in the root folder.

I moved it now to the public_html folder, and changed the RewriteRule to your suggestion, now I get 404 page not found. And if I go to mysite.co.za/dev I get the Index of page again.

Comment: can i get the url of your applicaiton?

Comment: Also remove all the contents of .htaccess and add the following and give a try: RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]